# SQAlchemy custom secondary relation with composite primary keys

Tags: sqlalchemy

There are 3 tables: `Account`, `Role`, `User`. Both `Role` and `User` have a foreign key `account_id` that points to `Account`.

A user can have multiple roles, hence the `roles_users` table which acts as the secondary relation table between `Role` and `User`.

The `Account` table is a tenant table for our app, it is used to separate different customers.

Note that all tables have (besides `Account`) have composite primary keys with `account_id`. This is done for a few reasons, but let's say it's done to keep everything consistent.

Now if I have a simple secondary relationship (`User.roles` - the one that is commented out) all works as expected. Well kind of.. it throws a legitimate warning (though I believe it should be an error):

```
SAWarning: relationship 'User.roles' will copy column role.account_id to column roles_users.account_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'User.roles' (copies user.account_id to roles_users.account_id). Consider applying viewonly=True to read-only relationships, or provide a primaryjoin condition marking writable columns with the foreign() annotation.
```

That's why I created the second relation `User.roles` - the one that is not commented out. Querying works as expected which has 2 conditions on join and everything. However I get this error when I try to save some roles on the user:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedColumnError: Can't execute sync rule for source column 'roles_users.role_id'; mapper 'Mapper|User|user' does not map this column.  Try using an explicit `foreign_keys` collection which does not include destination column 'role.id' (or use a viewonly=True relation).
```

As far as I understand it, SA is not able to figure out how to save the secondary because it has a custom `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` so it proposes to use `viewonly=True` which has the effect of just ignoring the roles relation when saving the model.

The question is how to save the roles for a user without having to do it by hand (the example is commented out in the code). In the real app we have many secondary relationships and we're saving them in many places. It would be super hard to rewrite them all.

Is there a solution to keep using `User.roles = some_roles` while keeping the custom `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` below?

The full example using SA 1.1.9:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Text, Table, ForeignKeyConstraint, ForeignKey, and_
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import foreign, relationship, Session

Base = declarative_base()


class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'account'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


roles_users = Table(
    'roles_users', Base.metadata,
    Column('account_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('role_id', Integer, primary_key=True),

    ForeignKeyConstraint(['user_id', 'account_id'], ['user.id', 'user.account_id']),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['role_id', 'account_id'], ['role.id', 'role.account_id']),
)


class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

    def __str__(self):
        return '<Role {} {}>'.format(self.id, self.name)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

    # This works as expected: It saves data in roles_users
    # roles = relationship(Role, secondary=roles_users)

    # This custom relationship - does not work
    roles = relationship(
        Role,
        secondary=roles_users,
        primaryjoin=and_(foreign(Role.id) == roles_users.c.role_id,
                         Role.account_id == roles_users.c.account_id),
        secondaryjoin=and_(foreign(id) == roles_users.c.user_id,
                           account_id == roles_users.c.account_id))


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session(engine)

# Create our account
a = Account()
session.add(a)
session.commit()

# Create 2 roles
u_role = Role()
u_role.id = 1
u_role.account_id = a.id
u_role.name = 'user'
session.add(u_role)

m_role = Role()
m_role.id = 2
m_role.account_id = a.id
m_role.name = 'member'
session.add(m_role)
session.commit()

# Create 1 user
u = User()
u.id = 1
u.account_id = a.id
u.name = 'user'

# This does not work
u.roles = [u_role, m_role]
session.add(u)
session.commit()

# Works as expected
i = roles_users.insert()
i = i.values([
    dict(account_id=a.id, role_id=u_role.id, user_id=u.id),
    dict(account_id=a.id, role_id=m_role.id, user_id=u.id),
])
session.execute(i)

# re-fetch user from db
u = session.query(User).first()
for r in u.roles:
    print(r)
```

**NOTE:** Switching `primaryjoin` with `secondaryjoin` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for posterity sake - switch foreign wrappers and careful with primary vs secondary joins:

Instead of this:

```py
    roles = relationship(
        Role,
        secondary=roles_users,
        primaryjoin=and_(foreign(Role.id) == roles_users.c.role_id,
                         Role.account_id == roles_users.c.account_id),
        secondaryjoin=and_(foreign(id) == roles_users.c.user_id,
                           account_id == roles_users.c.account_id))
```

Do this:

```py
    roles = relationship(
        Role,
        secondary=roles_users,
        primaryjoin=and_(id == foreign(roles_users.c.user_id), account_id == foreign(roles_users.c.account_id)),
        secondaryjoin=and_(Role.id == foreign(roles_users.c.role_id), Role.account_id == roles_users.c.account_id),
    )
```